# nuget fudged up my vs 2010 installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Installed nuget to make it easier to add references to my projects, something went wrong and vs 2010 stopped responding when i tried to start it. tried to open it through devenv /log and got 6 errors, managed to reinstall several programs so its just 1 left now.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.RiaComponents.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\RiaTools\DataBinding\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.RiaComponents.dll
```

Source:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost

The file isnt existing on my computer. Checked another computer i have with vs 2010 and there is no such file there either. This file cannot be downloaded nor i dont know where it comes from. I cannot start vs for more then 2 seconds and it doesnt work to start it in safemode either. Please help me get this file or reference me to where i can get it.

Answer (score 1):

It's from WCF RIA Services.

you can install it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28357 and give it another try.